# WPF TreeView binding multiple different dictionaries in different levels and sorting them by TKey

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have these Models:

```
public class CustomerGroup
  {
      public string GroupName { get; set; }
      public string GroupKey { get; set; }
  }
  public class Customer
  {
      public string GroupKey { get; set; }
      public string CustomerKey { get; set; }
      public string CustomerName { get; set; }
      // and more irrelevant stuff for my question...
  }
  public class ConstructionSite 
  {
      public string CustomerKey { get; set; }
      public string GroupeKey { get; set; }
      public string ConstructionSiteName { get; set; }
      // and more irrelevant stuff for my question...
  }
```

And i have these Dictionaries:

```
public class CustomerGroupList : List<CustomerGroup>
{
   // Methods for Serialization etc.
}
public class CustomersDictionary : SortedDictionary<string, List<Customer>> // TKey is GroupKey
{
   // Methods for Serialization etc.
}
public class ConstructionSiteDictionary : SortedDictionary<string, List<ConstructionSite>> // TKey is customerKey
{
   // Methods for Serialization etc.
}
```

So the customer's dictionary contains the groupKey as TKey and a list of customers for this group as value.
And the construction sites dictionary contains the CustomerKey as TKey and a list of construction sites for this customer as value.
And the Dictionaries are stored in a static class

Now I want to bind these dictionaries as source of an treeview and it should look like this:

```
-CustomerGroupOne
  -CustomerOne
    -Construction site A
    -Construction site B
  -CustomerTwo
    -ConSite C
-GroupTwo
  -CustomerThree
```

So I found a solution to Bind the data, BUT I can't figure out how to get the list from the dictionary with the key of the upper node's key.
I Expected it would work like this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static dataServices:DataProviderService.CustomerGroupsList}}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding GroupName}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static dataServices:DataProviderService.CustomersDictionary[GroupKeyOfUpperNodesCurrentGroup]}}">
                    <Label Content="{Binding CustomerName}"/>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static dataServices:DataProviderService.ConstructionSiteDictionary[CustomerKeyOfUpperNodesCorrentCustomer]}}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConstructionSiteName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

I hope anyone can help me. Thanks for any help!
Sorry for the bad English...
I'm going to school right now and just started with C# for a little more than one year...

Comment: See MVVM way to create a WPF App. Assign `DataContext` and don't use static data storage anymore because it isn't enough flexible way to do the bindings. Then you'll be able to play with data in C# class. The other way to solve is `IValueConverter` or `IMultiValueConverter` with `MultiBinding`.

Comment: @aepot Do you have any example? So I can't get do it in xaml and have to do it programmatically?

Comment: Xaml is murkup not programming language. You can set relations between UI and data but not change the data structure or establish relations between data and other data. Shortlt if you want to set child nodes in category, you must have that Property in data class. You may look for examples in www.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name `TreeView` implies, the control displays a *tree* data structure. But a dictionary is a flat collection of key-value pairs. Obviously the `Dictionary` is from data source. You have to convert the dictionary to the proper hierarchical data structure. It's recommended to have your data entities reflect the hierarchical data structure. A hierarchical data structure can be achieved by adding child collections to the data models:

**Hierarchical data structure**

```
public class CustomerGroup
{
  // Define a child collection
  public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

  public string GroupName { get; set; }
  public string GroupKey { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
  // Define a child collection
  public ObservableCollection<ConstructionSite> ConstructionSites { get; set; }

  public string GroupKey { get; set; }
  public string CustomerKey { get; set; }
  public string CustomerName { get; set; }
  // and more irrelevant stuff for my question...
}

public class ConstructionSite 
{
  public string CustomerKey { get; set; }
  public string GroupeKey { get; set; }
  public string ConstructionSiteName { get; set; }
  // and more irrelevant stuff for my question...
}
```

**DataSourceViewModel.cs**

class DataSourceViewModel : INot6ifyPropertyChanged
{
public ObservableCollection CustomerGroups { get; }

public DataSourceViewModel()
{
this.CustomerGroups = new ObservableCollection()
{
new CustomerGroup
{
CustomerGroupName = "CustomerGroupOne",
Customers = new Customer
{
CustomerName = "CustomerOne",
ConstructionSites = new ConstructionSite {ConstructionSiteName = "Construction site A"}
}
}
};
}

**MainWindow.xaml**
Define HieratchicalDataTemplates to display the structure and
assign `DataSourceViewModel` to the `DataContext` as non-static binding source.

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <DataSourceViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerGroups}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
    
      <!-- Root node -->
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType={x:Type CustomerGroup}" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType={x:Type Customer}" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ConstructionSites}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerName}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

      <!-- Leaf node -->
      <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type ConstructionSite}>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConstructionSitesName}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  </TreeView>
</Window>
```